# What could stop CSS with PHP variables from loading?

Tags: php, android, css

On the site: http://www.agricultureupdate.com/invest/new/index.php

I have used PHP to generate certain colors etc.

It works fine on all desktop laptops tested but it does load the css files (just loads html) on a galaxy note running android 4.04. The strange thing is it works on my own galaxy note running 4.1.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: What part doesn't work on 4.04? Colors, layout, etc?

Comment: "it does not work" <= elaborate please.

Comment: Sorry, the CSS files appear to not load at all. So the pure html is shown with no styles

Comment: You can have a look at the logcat output, could give you useful information about the reason of the failure.

Comment: Verify that the CSS files are being requested by looking at your web server logs. When PHP generates the CSS, is it sending a `content-type: text/css` header?

Comment: @GrantRichmond Clear the cache. What happends if you visit the CSS-url directly?

Comment: Since you are using jquery, who knows?
Does the same problem surface with a testpage without JQuery in it?

Comment: I have 
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    require_once('../config.php');
?>

at the top of the file so it returns as CSS file

Comment: what happens when you open the url of the CSS file directly in the browser? do you see valid CSS code? Or perhaps a blank page or a PHP error?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're parsing the CSS with PHP, why not just pull it straight into the template page

```
<style>
<?php require_once('path to php/css file'); ?>
</style>
```

The error is probably about the file types and headers, so this should work.